# How to get the zoom level of an svg image using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg image side by side with geojson. There are corresponding objects in both the images. I have added both of them using d3. I am currently able to zoom and pan them both separately. Now I want to get the value of zoom level whenever the user scrolls one any of the images. I want to print the value out on the console. No matter which scrolls (zoom in or zoom out) the value should print out to the console for every zoom scroll. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Sketch-To-Metric Map Alignment by Qualitative Spatial Constraint Matching</title>

    <!-- the data of the map -->
    <script src="img/sketchmap_ids.json"></script>

    <!--Add support for earlier versions of Internet Explorer -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="lib/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <filter id="offset" x="-20%" y="-10%" height="130%">
     <feGaussianBlur  in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5"/>
      <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="B"/>
     <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="B"/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

    <filter id="dropshadow_2" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur -->
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> <!-- how much to offset -->
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to -->
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <!-- circle r="10" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"/ -->

    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

    <style>
        .shadow {
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 5px 5px 5px 10px);
                    filter: drop-shadow( 5px 5px 2px); /* Same syntax as box-shadow */

        }
        .reveal section img { background:none; border:none; box-shadow:none; }
        .service {
            stroke-width: 4;
            stroke: #999999;
            fill: none;
        }
        .residential-line {
            stroke-width: 8;
            stroke: #b3b3b3;
            fill: none;
        }
        .fence,.footway,.cycleway,.track,.path,.pedestrian,.steps {
            stroke-width: 2;
            stroke: #2b1100;
            stroke-dasharray: 3,2,3;
            fill: none;
        }
        .primary {
            stroke-width: 18;
            stroke: #b3b3b3;
            fill: none;
        }
        .tertiary {
            stroke-width: 12;
            stroke: #b3b3b3;
            fill: none;
        }
        .bridge {
            stroke-width: 12;
            stroke: #cd853f;
            fill: none;
        }
        .graveyard {
            stroke-width: 2;
            stroke: #444444;
            stroke-dasharray: 3,2,3;
            fill: #668000;
        }
        .waterway-line,.river-line,.weir {
            stroke-width: 5;
            stroke: #2A7FFF;
            fill: none;
        }
        .water {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #0066FF;
            fill: #2A7FFF;;
        }
        .scrub,.forest {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #008033;
            fill: #008033;
        }
        .grass,.village_green,.greenhouse {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #5FD35F;
            fill: #5FD35F;
        }
        .residential,.commercial {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #FFF6D5;
            fill: #FFF6D5;
        }
        .parking,.bicycle_parking {
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke: #FFE680;
            fill: #FFE680;
        }
        .university,.civic,.yes,.house,.school {
            stroke-width: 0;
            fill: #916F6F;
        }
        .map-panel {
            width: 100%;   
            border: 1px solid #444444;
        }
        #sketch3,#sketch4,#sketch5,#sketch6,#sketch10,#sketchgraph11,#sketchgraph12 {
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
            padding-bottom:0px;
        }

        #metric3,#metric4,#metric5,#metric6,#metric10,#metricgraph11,#metricgraph12 {
            width: 45%;
            float: right;
            padding-bottom:0px;
        }

        .text-pane-left {
            width: 45%;
            float: right;
            padding-bottom:0px;
        }

        .text-pane-right {
            width: 45%;
            float: right;
            padding-bottom:0px;
        }

        #mynetwork {
            width: 854px;    
            height: 480px; 
            position: relative; 
            border: 1px solid #444444;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        #othernetwork {
            width: 800px;    
            height: 600px; 
            position: relative; 
            border: 1px solid #444444;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        #visualization {
            width: 800px;    
            height: 600px; 
            position: relative; 
            border: 1px solid #444444;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        body {
            color: #d3d3d3;
            font: 12pt arial;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>  
</head>

<body>

    <div class="map-panel" id="panel">
        <div class="map-pane-left" id="sketch4"></div>
        <div class="map-pane-right" id="metric4"></div>
    </div>                                                  

    <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3/topojson.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>





    <script>



        //load sketch map

        d3.xml("img/sketch_all_in_components_web.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml)           {
            if (error) throw error;

            function sketchMapZoomed() {
                    svg.selectAll("*").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + "                        scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
            }

      //var copy = xml.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById('sketch4').appendChild(xml.documentElement);
            d3.select('#sketch4').selectAll('g,                                                                     path').on('mouseenter',animateMapTargets).on('mouseleave',removeFilter);      
            var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", sketchMapZoomed ))
        });



        //load metric map




        var width = document.getElementById("sketch4").clientWidth;
        height = (width * 0.71053942806206943134954217685331);

        function metricMapZoomed () {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }

        var svg = d3.select("#metric4").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("id", "metricmap")
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", metricMapZoomed ))
      .append("g");

        //create a place holder rectangle to keep floats inline
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", width)
            .attr("id", "placeholder");

        d3.json("img/defense_data.json", function(error, map) {
            if (error) return console.error(error);

            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([7.612337603149424, 51.96211781909236])
                .scale(3000000);
                //.translate(0,0);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(projection);

            svg.selectAll(".city_block_landmarks")
                .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.city_block_landmarks).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.properties.class)
                    return d.properties.classfeature;
                })
                .attr("id", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.id)
                    return d.id;
                })
                .attr("d", path);

            svg.selectAll(".hidden_landmarks")
                .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.hidden_landmarks).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.properties.class)
                    return d.properties.classfeature;
                })
                .attr("id", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.id)
                    return d.id;
                })
                .attr("d", path);

            svg.selectAll(".botanica_mid_polygons")
                .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.botanica_mid_polygons).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.properties.class)
                    return d.properties.classfeature;
                })
                .attr("id", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.id)
                    return d.id;
                })
                .attr("d", path);

            svg.selectAll(".streets_linear_features")
                .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.streets_linear_features).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.properties.class)
                    return d.properties.classfeature;
                })
                .attr("id", function(d){
                    //console.log(d.id)
                    return d.id;
                })
                .attr("d", path);   
        });

        //animate objects on mouse on and remove animation on mouse off
        function animateMapTargets() {          
            if (this.id)
                if (targets[this.id])
                    targets[this.id].forEach(animateTargetNode);
        };

        function animateTargetNode(obj, i) {
            //console.log(d3.select('#'+obj)./*node().*/style('filter','url(#offset)'));
            //d3.select('#'+obj).style('filter','url(#offset)');
            //console.log(d3.select('#'+obj).classed("shadow", true));//
            d3.select('#'+obj).classed("shadow", true);
                //.attr()  style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"
                //.attr();
        }

        function removeFilter() {           
            if (this.id)
                if (targets[this.id])
                    targets[this.id].forEach(function animateTargetNode(obj, i) {
                        //d3.select('#'+obj).style('filter','none');
                        d3.select('#'+obj).classed("shadow", false);
                    });
        };




    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`zoom` events](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-events) have a `transform` property:

> event.transform - the current zoom transform.

The [zoom transform documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-transforms) has a nice explanation of how it is internally implemented and why. In short they are implemented as a matrix that can represent a translation and a scale and the `transform` exposes them via properties. The "zoom level" would then be the `scale`:

> transform.k - the scale factor k.

So a `zoom` event handler like this should work:

```
function zoomed(event) {
    console.log(event.transform.k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to mmlr's answer

**d3.event.transform.k** worked for me instead of *event.transform.k*